# ShareThis: the subject shows up in the To field of an email client for the email share button

Tags: sharethis

I am supporting a website that uses ShareThis. I notice that the email share is not configured properly. If one clicks on the email button, the following

```
&subject=I'd like to share a link with you
```

shows up in the "To" field of the mail client such as desktop Outlook. How can to fix this? The following is the ShareThis code the site uses:

```
window.__sharethis__.load('inline-share-buttons', {
    alignment: 'right',
    id: 'share-buttons',
    enabled: true,
    font_size: 12,
    padding: 3,
    radius: 2,
    networks: ['facebook', 'twitter', 'reddit',   'email', 'sharethis'],  
    size: 18,
    show_mobile_buttons: true,
    spacing: 4
});
```

Comment: The reason behind this is that the mailto link generated by sharethis is "?to=&subject=I'd like to share a link with you"  Outlook does not handle the empty to parameter correctly.  I'm also having this problem and going to try intercepting the event to remove the empty to parameter.  I'll post back if I get something to work.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built-in way with the ShareThis API to correct this issue but you can work around it by handling the share this onLoad event and intercepting the email button click event.  I'm using jQuery but it's easy enough to accomplish the same thing with vanilla JS.

```
window.__sharethis__.load('inline-share-buttons', {
  alignment: 'right',
  id: 'share-buttons',
  enabled: true,
  font_size: 12,
  padding: 3,
  radius: 2,
  networks: ['facebook', 'twitter', 'reddit',   'email', 'sharethis'],  
  size: 18,
  show_mobile_buttons: true,
  spacing: 4,
  onLoad: function () {
    //override the default email sharing functionality since it's broken in outlook
    $('.st-btn[data-network=email]').on('click', function (e) {
      var subject = "I'd like to share a link with you";
      var body = $('#share-buttons').data('url');
      document.location = "mailto:?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + body;

      //Prevent default share this functionality
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
  }
});
```